# Maximum number of non-overlapping spheres covering a sphere?

Tags: geometry, spheres, packing-problem

I would like to know if there is a formula, or at least some bounds, for the following problem. Consider a (three-dimensional) sphere of radius R. What is the maximum number of equal spheres, all of radius $r<R$, that I can put on the surface of the large sphere without having the small spheres overlap? The arrangement need not be regular. That is, the requirements are 1. that the centers of the small spheres are all at $R+r$ from the center of the large central sphere; and 2. that the centers of the small spheres are at least $2r$ apart from each other.

I have googled quite a bit and came across various papers about the kissing number (which is a more restricted problem) and spherical codes, but if I understand it correctly, the latter is not quite the problem I consider, because the minimum distance is to be maximized rather than minimized.

Comment: This looks equivalent to placing points on the surface of the big sphere so they are all at least a given distance apart, where that distance is $2R\frac{r}{R+r}$ as a straight line through the big sphere or $2R\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{R+r}\right)$ as the great-circle arc of the big sphere.  This is the kissing number when $r=R$.  It is in a sense the reverse of the Tammes problem which asks for the distances for given number of small points/circles/spheres.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2536 may be of interest

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's not quite what I need. I want to have the small spheres as closely spaced as possible, but without overlapping, whereas Tammes wanted to have them as far apart from each other as possible. The paper you suggested and others on the problem always assume the number of small spheres to be given, whereas I need the number as a result. So it's indeed the reverse of a related problem, but the Tammes-type papers don't seem to offer a possibility to solve for $N$ for given $r$ and $R$.

Comment: This seems related, if not equivalent, to the [Thomson's packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem). As Wikipedia says, "*configurations have been rigorously identified in only a handful of cases*". The problem is that there are no regular tilings of the sphere with arbitrarily small tiles, in contrast to the plane.

Comment: Suppose for example $r=10$ and $R=50$.  Then the angle allowed between centres of the small spheres has to be at least $2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{10}{50+10}\right) \approx 0.57339$ radians or $32.853^\circ$.  Look this up in a [table for sphere packing](http://neilsloane.com/packings/index.html#I) and this suggests that the best known solution (in 1996) would have $40$ small spheres (angle $33.1583563^\circ$) while $41$ small spheres (best angle found $32.7290944^\circ$) may not be possible.  I doubt there is a much better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess what I will do is to calculate the volume of the spherical shell between $R$ and $R+2r$ and of the "cuboid" sector that just encloses one of the small spheres. The floor of the ratio of these volumes should at least give an upper bound on the number, and given that for my purposes usually $r\ll R$, that might be not too bad.

Comment: Consider the intersection of your spheres with the sphere of radius $R+r$. This will give a packing of the sphere by balls of the radius close to $r$ (you can calculate what it is from simple geometry). So you can get a rough estimate by dividing the surface volume of the $R+r$ sphere by the volume of (spherical) ball of that radius.

Comment: User Spektre posted an interesting approach somewhat similar to my own on Stackoverflow, where I had posted the question originally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415825/maximum-number-of-non-overlapping-spheres-covering-a-sphere/59434955#59434955